# symfonyのCrawlerでxmlにノードを追加したい

Tags: php, symfony2, xml

symfonyのCrawlerを使ってxmlにノードを追加したいと思い下記のように実装しました。

```
//analyticsController.php
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;

public function analize() {
    $node = $this->generateDOMNode('ksj:station', 'xlink:href', '');
    $crawler->filter('ksj|Dataset ksj|RailroadSection')->addNode($node);
    $stations = $crawler->filter('ksj|Dataset ksj|RailroadSection ksj|station')->extract('xlink:href');
    var_dump($stations);
}

private function generateDOMNode($nodeName, $attr, $nodeValue){
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $node = $dom->createElement($nodeName, $nodeValue);
    $attribute = $dom->createAttribute($attr);
    $attribute->value = "hello";
    $node->appendChild($attribute);
    return $node;
}
```

こちらを実行してもなぜか"hello"を返してくれません。

実際のxmlデータは下記のようななものです。

```
//railRoad.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ksj:Dataset>
 <ksj:RailroadSection gml:id="eb02_1">
  <ksj:location xlink:href="#cv_rss1"/>
  <ksj:railwayType>23</ksj:railwayType>
  <ksj:serviceProviderType>5</ksj:serviceProviderType>
  <ksj:railwayLineName>沖縄都市モノレール線</ksj:railwayLineName>
  <ksj:operationCompany>沖縄都市モノレール</ksj:operationCompany>
</ksj:RailroadSection>
</ksj:Dataset>
```

上記のxmlデータを下記のように変えたいと思っています。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ksj:Dataset>
 <ksj:RailroadSection gml:id="eb02_1">
  <ksj:location xlink:href="#cv_rss1"/>
  <ksj:railwayType>23</ksj:railwayType>
  <ksj:serviceProviderType>5</ksj:serviceProviderType>
  <ksj:railwayLineName>沖縄都市モノレール線</ksj:railwayLineName>
  <ksj:operationCompany>沖縄都市モノレール</ksj:operationCompany>
  <ksj:station>hello</ksj:station>
</ksj:RailroadSection>
</ksj:Dataset>
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: filter で station node を取り出す直前に saveXML() で ksj:Dataset node 全体を dump して確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @heliac2001 有難うございます。crawlerでsaveXML()に対応する関数ってありましたでしょうか？ドキュメントみても見当たらず。。http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html

Comment: ええと、「$crawler->first()->saveXml()」などでできませんでしたっけ？

Comment: @heliac2001できないです。。first()メソッドはcrwalerオブジェクトをリターンするのですが、cralwer自体がsaveXMLに相当するメソッドを持ってない気がします。

Comment: すみません、それでは「$crawler->first()->ownerDocument->saveXml($crawler->first());」ではいかがでしょうか？

Comment: @heliac2001 
ownerDocument()もcrawlerは持っていません。。

Comment: どうもすみません、色々と勘違いをしていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLドキュメント自体を処理することが目的の場合、Symfony/DomCrawlerは使えません。
理由は、Symfony/DomCrawlerは、各種メソッド（`filter()`など）実行のたびに、状態が適用された「新しいCrawlerインスタンス」を返すようになっているからです。
提示されているコードだと、

```
$crawler->filter('ksj|Dataset ksj|RailroadSection')->addNode($node);
```

この最初の `filter()` で新しい`Crawler`インスタンスが作られます。新しい`Crawler`は、セレクタで指定したノードだけを持ち、元のXMLドキュメント（に対応するCrawler）とはまったく別のインスタンスになります。ここにノードを追加したとしても、元のドキュメント構造は変化しません。

XMLを操作したい場合は、PHPが持つDOM関連機能（DOMとXPath) あたりで解決してはいかがでしょうか。

例に挙げられている処理（XMLドキュメントの特定の箇所に、ノードを追加する）であれば、次のようなコードになります。

```
<?php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(file_get_contents('railroad.xml'));

$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//ksj:Dataset/ksj:RailroadSection");

$adding = generateDOMNode('ksj:station', 'xlink:href', '', $document);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->appendChild($adding);
}

function generateDOMNode($nodeName, $attr, $nodeValue, $document)
{
    $node = $document->createElement($nodeName, $nodeValue);
    $node->setAttribute($attr, "hello");
    return $node;
}

$xml = $document->saveXML();

// stationのxlinkだけを取り出す
$document2 = new DOMDocument();
$document2->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document2);
$stations = $xpath->query("//ksj:Dataset/ksj:RailroadSection/ksj:station/@xlink:href");

foreach ($stations as $station) {
    echo $station->value;
}
```

（参考までに、namespaceを付加したXMLファイルも貼っておきます）

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ksj:Dataset xmlns:ksj="http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/schemas/ksj-app"  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <ksj:RailroadSection gml:id="eb02_1">
        <ksj:location xlink:href="#cv_rss1"/>
        <ksj:railwayType>23</ksj:railwayType>
        <ksj:serviceProviderType>5</ksj:serviceProviderType>
        <ksj:railwayLineName>沖縄都市モノレール線</ksj:railwayLineName>
        <ksj:operationCompany>沖縄都市モノレール</ksj:operationCompany>
    </ksj:RailroadSection>
</ksj:Dataset>
```

なお、XPathの構文などについては[MSDNのページ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)が参考になります。